# Unique session WordPress

Tags: php, session

I want to allow only one session at the time across browsers and PCs. I want to "disconect" or log out to the old session if a new session starts in Wordpress.

Comment: WordPress doesn't use sessions, it uses cookies.

Comment: Using cookies exist a way?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by changing `LOGGED_IN_KEY` constant in your `wp-config.php` before logging in.

```
define('AUTH_KEY', 'put your unique phrase here');
```

**Update**: it's better to invalidate all secret keys. They can be generated by Wordpress own generator here: https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @Chris_O, really?    
> You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies. This does mean that all users will have to login again.    
http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Security_Keys